# Apache Commons VFS - cannot resolveFile

Tags: java, jboss, apache-commons-vfs

The VFS method cannot process this URI `${jboss.server.temp.dir}/local/outgoing` configured in `jboss-beans.xml` which is resolved to `"C:\\Download\\jboss-eap-5.1.1\\server\\default\\tmp/local/outgoing"` by JBoss. When I try to resolve the URI and get the file, it throws an exception. Any ideas what could be the problem?

`Exception`

```
17:35:25,024 ERROR [VfsSynchronizerConfImpl] File FromOutgoing cannot be resolved, FileSystemException:
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not find file with URI "C:\Download\jboss-eap-5.1.1\server\default\tmp/local/outgoing" because it is a relative path, and no base URI was provided.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:719)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:649)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:605)
```

`DefaultFileSystemManager.class methods`

```
public FileObject resolveFile(final String uri) throws FileSystemException
  -- this method calls the method below

public FileObject resolveFile(final FileObject baseFile, final String uri,
        final FileSystemOptions fileSystemOptions)
        throws FileSystemException
  -- this method cannot process the string and throws
     throw new FileSystemException("vfs.impl/find-rel-file.error", uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it needs the file: scheme because the error says it's asumed to be relative.

Comment: Scheme didn't help. But the problem was one instance of FileSystemManager. It should be created new for every operation.

Answer (score 16):

Quite old question but popular. This exception is quite generic. For my case, this exception was thrown while uploading files to remote ftp server. And the root cause was missing sftp library in classpath. Just before this exception, `vfs` tries to resolve the file using one of the provider corresponding to the scheme mentioned in `URI`.

For my case, scheme was `sftp` and and it tried to find `jsch` library on classpath. Since, it was not present on my classpath, this exception was thrown.Therefore, one must keep the provider jar on classpath.

Comment: This was indeed my case. Spent few hours and got your answer.

Comment: This was my case as well. If you are using apache commons VFS2 and the scheme is SFTP make sure to include jsch library in the classpath.

Answer (score 9):

@Manish Bansal - thank you for your reply on this issue.
I tried everything but was still getting the same error: exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.vfs2.filesystemexception: could not find file with uri "sftp://....." because it is a relative path, and no base uri was provided.

In my MAVEN project i had to add the dependency for 'jsch' & it worked.

So, in a nutshell i added the following POM dependencies:

```
<!-- SFTP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>   
    <version>0.1.55</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public void downloadFile() throws IOException {     
    FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
            
    FileObject remote = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString("XYZ.com","ABC","LMNOP","/<FOLDER_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>"));
    FileObject local = manager.resolveFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "src//main//resources//");
    
    local.copyFrom(remote, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
 
    local.close();
    remote.close();
}

public static URI createConnectionString(String hostName, String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {        
    URI sftpURI = null;
    try {
        String userInfo = username + ":" + password;
        
        sftpURI = new URI("sftp",userInfo,hostName,-1,remoteFilePath,null,null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return sftpURI;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I was struggling with the error reported by the OP, and adding a maven dependency for jsch has fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

For other people facing with this issue: I got rid of this error by replacing

```
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
```

with

```
StandardFileSystemManager fsManager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
fsManager.init();
```

This allowed me to use the file system manager multiple times without getting the error anymore described in the question. Don't forget to close you `fsManager` when you're done with it:

```
fsManager.close();
```

Comment: if you check the code behind `VFS.getManager()` you'll see that it creates a static instance of `StandardFileSystemManager` and initiate it for you or return the current instance.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, as I was connecting to the same SFTP using different users

Comment: Thanks, you save my life! I encounter the same issue, first time works, subsequent failed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to try to complement correct answers already provided.
*In short*: check [VFS Dependencies Table](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/build.html) for VFS features you use.

---

I ran into a similar problem when I first tried to connect over `FTP` (*not SFTP as in the original question*). I use Maven with IntelliJ IDEA.
I looked through the [VFS official docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) and found out the following:

1. Some of [VFS Project Dependencies](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/commons-vfs2/dependencies.html) are optional and **not installed by default**.
2. What **one can need to install** is on the [table in VFS Download & Build page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/build.html).
   Indeed, `JSch` is required for `SFTP`, `Apache Commons Net` is required for `FTP`, etc.

My FTP connection had begun work as soon as I installed `Commons Net` via Maven.

**EDIT 2023**: Namely, add in your `pom.xml`:

```html
<!-- FTP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```