# Uploading to remote FTP server using Apache Commons VFS

Tags: java, aws-lambda, sftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-vfs

I'm attempting to upload a zipped file to a remote FTP server using Apache VFS. The environment in which this is being executed in is an AWS Java 8 Lambda if it's relevant. This is my current implementation which generally follows the example provided [here](https://www.memorylack.com/apache-commons-vfs-for-sftp/):

```
public static FileSystemOptions createDefaultOptions()
      throws FileSystemException {
    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(
        opts, "no");

    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, true);

    return opts;
}

public void uploadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    StandardFileSystemManager fsManager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
    fsManager.init();

    FileObject localFile = fsManager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    FileObject remote = fsManager.resolveFile(
        "sftp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DOMAINNAME>.com/tmp1.zip");

    remote.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
    remote.close();
}
```

When I call this method with a well-defined file that I confirmed exists in the Lambda, I get an error of:

```
event_description="Could not find file with URI 
"sftp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DOMAINNAME>.com/tmp1.zip" 
because it is a relative path, and no base URI was provided."
```

I have been able to connect to the server via FTP on the Terminal using the same credentials, so I don't think it's related to those. Another question which I've looked at which might be relevant can be found here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998574/apache-commons-vfs-cannot-resolvefile), although I've already implemented it's suggestion and am still getting the same "no base URI" error.

Comment: I think the relative path error means it did not recognize sftp: as a supported method. This happens when the sftp provider is not properly loaded or missing dependencies. Try to instantiate the provider manually, that will give you a helpful exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the FileSystemOptions with SftpFileSystemConfigs when you are resolving the remote file through SFTP in VFS.
So instead of,

```
FileObject remote = fsManager.resolveFile("sftp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DOMAINNAME>.com/tmp1.zip");
```

try,

```
try {
    FileObject remote = fsManager.resolveFile("sftp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DOMAINNAME>.com/tmp1.zip",createDefaultOptions());
} catch(FileSystemException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you may need to handle the FileSystemException accrodingly either through a try/catch or throwing the exception with method signature.